# angular, title is undefined error

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I have the following pieces of a file for a mean stack application.
The server side returns perfect valid data from the MongoDB.

**book.ts**

```
export class Book {
    isbn: string;
    title: string;
    author: string;
    publisher: string;
    price: number;
    update_date: Date;
}
```

**book.service.ts**

inside this file, I have the following method

```
 showBook(id): Promise<Book> {
        return this.http.get('/book/' + id)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Book)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

and a component file

**book-detail.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getBookDetail(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
}

// id is passed on via a router.navigate and it is a valid id

getBookDetail(id): void {
    console.log('ekgnjk');
    this.bookService.showBook(id)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.book = res;
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

**book-detail.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{book.title}}</h1>
    <dl class="list">
        <dt>ISBN</dt>
        <dd>{{book.isbn}}</dd>
        <dt>Title</dt>
        <dd>{{book.title}}</dd>
        <dt>Author</dt>
        <dd>{{book.author}}</dd>
        <dt>Publisher</dt>
        <dd>{{book.publisher}}</dd>
        <dt>Price</dt>
        <dd>{{book.price}}</dd>
        <dt>Last Updated</dt>
        <dd>{{book.updated_at}}</dd>
    </dl>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a [routerLink]="['/books']" class="btn btn-success">Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I run this app, I get the following error.

cannot read property title of undefined.

Title is the only property that is showing this error.
All other property returns valid data.
Also in the view, I can see my title property.
But in the terminal, I see the above-mentioned error.

But when I change the service code to the following,

**book.service.ts**

```
  showBook(id): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.get('/book/' + id)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

My application doesn't show any error.

Why does this happen? And why there is no error showing for other properties.

My MongoDB schema is as shown below;

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    isbn: String,
    title: String,
    author: String,
    publisher: String,
    price: Number,
    update_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the view is `initialized` and tries to show your data binding, you haven't got your book yet, server call works asynchronous, it waits until the call will be back, JS Thread will finish its work and then call the `then` functions from the event loop to assign the value to your book. At this time (during the above mentioned jobs) your `book` in `undefined`. So when it wants to access the property `title` on the `book` and because `book` is undefined, it throws the error

> Cannot read property title of undefined

You can use `?` safe checking operator in the view or initialize your variable `book`.

Either `<h1>{{book?.title}}</h1>` or `this.book = new Book()`; with appropriate parameters.

Comment: initialize my book in the component.ts file?

Comment: Yes also you can do via that. Updated

Comment: Or I can use *ngIf on book as well on component.html right?

Comment: Yes you can. But `ngIf` will cause your component to check also that during the change detection

Comment: I didn't get the change detection scenario. Can you explain it please?

Comment: Its a big theme, You can read https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: So, since i called title first it shows me the error on title,right? If it was isbn then i get an error on it,right?

Answer (score 1):

If the returned value doesn't contain a title,

```
response.json() as Book
```

won't cause it to be added.

You can use the safe-navigation operator to avoid getting an error

```
<h1>{{book?.title}}</h1>
```

Comment: I did used this and its not showing any error. But can you specify why such an error in detail. If i dont use a safe-navigation